# "Услуги по маникюру" — можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Маникюрные услуги", а как сказать иначе? "Услуги маникюра" или "услуги по маникюру" — как правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Маникюрные услуги*** - вполне нормально, зачем что-то искать - и что именно?
Разве что ***Услуги маникюрши***.  
Все остальное (а придумать можно еще и *на маникюр* и т.п.) в разной степени двусмысленно или косноязычно. Но, если уж выбирать из двух зайцев, то "наименее неправильно" *услуги по маникюру*. По крайней мере - не так двусмысленно.

Comment: В интернете встречаются часто такие варианты: "Услуги: маникюр, педикюр..." И "Услуги маникюра". Хотя мне последнее не нравится.

Answer (score 0):

Последняя фраза звучит так, будто бы услуги предлагает маникюр.Лучше и правильнее:Маникюрные услуги или: Услуги: маникюр,педюкир (здесь,если в список входят больше, чем одна услуга).Искать другие названия не вижу смысла.